# A specific key combination sporadically does not work on wired Apple keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, hardware-failure

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does not work on my wired aluminum apple keyboard with numpad. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> *does* work some of the time, such as after rebooting or after replugging the keyboard back in. These tricks do not work consistently, however.

I have seen this issue on with the same apple keyboard on 2 different machines: a macbook pro and a pc running Windows 10.

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how I could go about debugging this?

Comment: Also related: https://superuser.com/questions/1321854/shift-p-does-not-work-on-apple-keyboard and https://superuser.com/questions/1321854/shift-p-does-not-work-on-apple-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store.

Test both left & right shift keys, with & without other letters in combination. Especially test around w - a, q, 2, 3, 4, e, d, s. The circuit tracks tend to run in diagonals, so frequently there's a little pattern that forms if a track is damaged.

Test if the same data is received at all times, ie when your issue is happening & when it is not.

That will test for whether the issue is physically within the keyboard itself - which it sounds like it is.

Note: the option to record key ups & modifiers is harder to follow on-screen, but gives more precise information.

I don't know whether they key-caps are easy to remove & replace; many aren't on older keyboards like this one. I wouldn't recommend prying one off to clean underneath unless you're willing to risk it being permanently damaged.

Also - the massive price hike on these keyboards was fortunately quite short-lived after Apple stopped making them. You can get them for about $£€ 40 again now. They are essentially unrepairable, as they're glued together, so always having a spare can be a good idea. I find they usually last until you spill something on them or wear all the letters off ;)

Comment: All the above tests worked except left shift + w. Sounds like it may be a hardware issue with the keyboard. The fact that it sporadically works gives me hope that it might be repairable. I might try to clean under the key. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Wish you luck. I've only once tried to take one apart, after using an entire can of contact cleaner trying to clean up a spill - I wasn't very successful. Since then if one fails I just get a new one :\